# Omit matched object between Arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare newProp (Array of objects) with prop (Another array of objects), and when there is a match, it will be removed off newProp array.

```
prop = [{ id: 1, name: 'John Doe}, {id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe'}, {id: 3. name: 'Baby Doe'}]

newProp = [{id: 4, name: 'Johnny Doe' }, {id: 1, name: 'John Doe'} ....]
```

Here is what I have tried, wonder if there is better / cleaner way of solving this problem.

```js
  let prop = [{ id: 1, name: 'John Doe'}, {id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe'}, {id: 3, name: 'Baby Doe'}]

  let newProp = [{id: 4, name: 'Johnny Doe' }, {id: 1, name: 'John Doe'}]

prop.map( (i,Iindex) => {
    newProp.map((o, oIndex ) => {
      if (i.id == o.id) {
        prop.splice(Iindex, 1);
        console.log(prop);
      } 
    })
})
```

Comment: "it will be removed off newProp array" but the example removes them from prop ..

Comment: @Slai Yes, the code and the description are mismatching

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to `filter()` out the items you don't need.

It's cleaner and more readable (you'd see it all over the place in code of folks who follow functional programming), however it produces a new array, thus negatively affecting performance if called very frequently on very large input arrays.

```
newProp = newProp
  .filter(newPropElement =>
     prop.every(propElement => newPropElement.id !== propElement.id)
  )
```